# How to make video go forwards and backwards using the mouse scroll wheel in Celluloid video player?

Tags: video, video-player

How to attach mouse scroll wheel with Celluloid video player to forward & backward video?

Which command should I run for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how to use a mpv-style scroll gesture for celluloid:

1. Paste the following into `~/.config/celluloid/input.conf`:

   ```
   WHEEL_UP seek -1
   WHEEL_DOWN seek 1
   ```
2. Open Celluloid's *Preferences*:

   [image: celluloid preferences]
3. Pick that file as the *mpv input configuration file* in the *Config Files* tab:

   [image: mpv config file screen]
4. Enable *Load mpv input configuration file*:

   [image: mpv input config enabled]

Now Celluloid should be able to scroll the video time, not the volume. Just swap the `-1` and `1` if you want to reverse the scroll direction.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel T. Your solution works like magic. Thanks.